# SQL Server 2005 pivot query help

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I'm trying out the pivot function in SQL Server 2005 for the first time and running into a wall getting the result set I desire.

I have two tables `defects` and `employees`. I'm trying to get all the defects for employees in my `employee` table and I don't care about any defects assigned to people outside those that are entered in my employee table (I am thinking to join to it, I have not tried a sub query yet but don't think I'll need to)

I want to get results grouped by (pivoted on) `defects.severity` field. The fields I want in the result set are: `severity, assigned to, employee.name, fix data`

Basically I want to roll up the data according to severity and show a count based on the severity levels of defects

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ManagerId] [int] NULL,
    [NTID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ReportingGroup] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Added] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[defects]
(
    [Defect ID] [float] NULL,
    [SubSystem] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Severity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FixDate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Assigned To] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Summary] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product List] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Development Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Defect Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Defect Cause] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Est Ready for Retest] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Fix Stage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Planned Fix in Deployment Event] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Planned Fix in Event Mgmt Group] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Est Fixed Date] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Other Owner] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)
```

Comment: `[Defect ID] [float] NULL` doesn't seem to be the best choice for a primary key (which I assume it should be) for that table..... why **float**?? Why **NULL** ?? Why a space in the field name??? I would prefer `[DefectID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)` in all cases...

Comment: Do you want to PIVOT your results on Severity? (as in the differents values of severity should be different columns of your result set), or do you want to simply GROUP by severity?. Also, i don't see a [Fix data] column, just [FixDate]

Comment: Sorry, but as soon as I saw that you had embedded spaces in your column names, I thought "no way am I working on this".

Comment: the spaces in the col names is a pain, i just use [col name] to work with this. (thats how i get the data dump)  @ marc_s why do i need a primary key? im just grouping by business Severity field and listing totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it with this SQL:

```
select [Assigned To], [1-Urgent],[2-High],[3-Medium],[4-Low]
from (select [assigned to],[Business Severity] from defects where [assigned to] is not null) D
pivot
(count([Business Severity]) for [Business Severity] in ([1-Urgent],[2-High],[3-Medium],[4-Low])) V
```

thanks all

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer, then future visitors will know that this is resolved.